# "dielectric constant" or "electrical permittivity"?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electrostatics

What are the differences between "dielectric constant" and "electrical permittivity"?

By searching on the net, I found **[permittivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permittivity) = absolute permittivity**, which is the measure of capacitance that is encountered when forming an electric field in a particular medium. The lowest permittivity is that of a vacuum: **vacuum permittivity = electric constant**. In addition, **relative permittivity** of a dielectric medium is represented by the ratio of its **absolute permittivity** to the **electric constant**.

Therefore, I think the "electrical permittivity" in many literatures should be equivalent to **absolute permittivity** above. But what is "dielectric constant"? Any suggestion?

Comment: What did you not understand about the definitions given at the beginning of the Wikipedia link that you provided? It clearly states that dielectric constant is another name for relative permittivity, and both are simply the ratio of absolute permittivity to the permittivity of free space, $\epsilon_0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dielectric constant is the same thing as relative permittivity and is equal to the ratio of the electrical permittivity of a material to the electrical permittivity of a vacuum, or

$$ε_{r}(ω)=\frac{ε(ω)}{ε_o}$$

The electrical permittivity is generally a function of frequency, $ω$

The permittivity of free space, $ε_o$, is 8.85 x $10^{-12}$ F/m. The relative permittivity of a vacuum is by definition 1.

Absolute permittivity is just another name for permittivity.

Hope this helps.

Comment: did you mean "dielectric constant is another name for relative permittivity" by the last sentence?

Comment: @Enter Yes, that is my understanding. Check the following link: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Tables/diel.html

Comment: as to the permittivity to be a function of frequency, did you mean the frequency of AC?

Comment: Absolute permittivity of dielectric media, more often just called permittivity, is not the same as relative permittivity.

Comment: @Enter Yes. $ω$ is the angular frequency (radians per second) = $2πf$. Where $f$ is the AC frequency in Hz. Typically it is the static permittivity of materials tat are reported.

Comment: @amateurAstro According to Wikipedia, absolute permittivity is often simply called permittivity. But I suppose  there are other  definitions. What is your understanding of the difference, if any, between absolute permittivity and simply permittivity? Can you cite references?

Comment: @BobD I never said that absolute permittivity was different than permittivity. In fact, I said they were the same in common usage. However, I did say that that the last sentance in your answer is not correct. Relative permittivity, as defined in the equation in your answer, is the ratio of permittivity to $\epsilon_0$.

Comment: @amateurAstro Ah yes, I see now what you mean,"relative" slipped in there.. Revised. Thanks for pointing out